# Redirección https

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, .htaccess

Quiero redireccionar a los usuarios en mi página a una conexión segura forzando el `https`, pero cuando edito mi `.htaccess`, este hace que reaparezca el `/public` de mi proyecto Laravel, tan molesto en mi URL. A continuación el código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Trata con este método,

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.tupaginaweb.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tupoaginaweb.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.tupoaginaweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Espero que te funcione.